# Magento 2 - Autoload error Module 'Iazel_RegenProductUrl'

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, composer

**After update composer**

Please help me, I get this error.

> Module 'Iazel_RegenProductUrl' from '/var/www/vhosts/exm.com/httpdocs/app/code/Iazel/RegenProductUrl' has been already defined in '/var/www/vhosts/exm.com/httpdocs/vendor/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls/Iazel/RegenProductUrl'.

Comment: check if you have another `registration.php` file in a differen module that registers the `Iazel_RegenProductUrl` module. Maybe in `app/code`.

Comment: @Marius yes i have

Comment: plz help me any idea for this error

Comment: this is my live site

Comment: Take backup of `app/code/Iazel/RegenProductUrl` and remove `Iazel/RegenProductUrl` folder.

Comment: php bin/magento module:disable --clear-static-content Iazel_RegenProductUrl -> run this command face error "Autoload error
Module 'Iazel_RegenProductUrl' from '/var/www/vhosts/" this

Comment: i am really happy your advice thq so much guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments....
It looks like you have to versions of the same module. One in `vendor` and another one in `app/code`.
Remove the one from `app/code`, and clear the cache.
If you don't want to remove the module for some reason, you can just rename `registration.php` from the `app/code` module to anything else.

Comment: Sir you are great thq so much

Comment: sir one more que. how to use this module do you know

Comment: ask the developer. I have no idea

Comment: @DineshThakur Is this third party module or you have created?

Comment: No i have not created this module

Comment: and i dont know what is work for my site

Comment: You need to change `RegenProductUrl` name in all file because you can not use the same namespace module twise.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh ok i'll check and change name